# Fail to import typescript module built from bazel

Tags: typescript, node-modules, bazel

I try to build a node module using [@bazel/typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bazel/typescrip) and [npm_package](https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_nodejs/npm_package/npm_package.html#npm_package) rules of bazel using `bazel build //core:package`. Below is my BUILD file

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_library")
load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:defs.bzl", "npm_package")

ts_library(
  name = "core",
  srcs = glob(["*.ts"]),
)

npm_package(
  name = "package",
  srcs = ["package.json"],
  deps = [":core"],
  replacements = {"//internal/": "//"},
)
```

Then I run `bazel run //core:package.pack` and it generates a `.tgz` file and I install this module by running `npm install ./xxx.tgz -s`. Everything works well until I try to import this module using `import * as core from 'core';`

It gives me error says `Error: Cannot find module 'core/index'`

The declaration files of the module looks like this

```
/// <amd-module name="core/index" />
export * from './public_api';

/// <amd-module name="core/public_api" />
export declare const foo = "foo";
export declare const bar = "bar";
```

My questions are:

1. it is not able to imported because it is a amd module?
2. how to I resolve this issue?

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I find the answer myself. From ts_library doc, it does not explain and list an example to use a parameter called

```
module_name
```

If you do not pass this parameter when you try to build **a module**, it will make the file path as the module name which will cause importing issues.